# Error: Package: libmodule-10.0.0.1826-b10_0_0_1826.x86_64 (installed)

Tags: redhat, yum, rhel6

I am getting the following messages when running `yum update` on my RHEL 6 server. I have tried searching on the `libmodule-10.0.0.1826-b10_0_0_1826.x86_64` package and dependencies but can't find a solution.

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Update Process
rhel-x86_64-server-6                                     | 1.8 kB     00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package unixODBC.x86_64 0:2.2.11-7.1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libodbc.so.1()(64bit) for package: libmodule-10.0.0.1826-b10_0_0_1826.x86_64
---> Package unixODBC.x86_64 0:2.2.14-14.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libltdl.so.7()(64bit) for package: unixODBC-2.2.14-14.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libtool-ltdl.x86_64 0:2.2.6-15.5.el6 will be installed
---> Package unixODBC.x86_64 0:2.2.11-7.1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libodbc.so.1()(64bit) for package: libmodule-10.0.0.1826-b10_0_0_1826.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: libmodule-10.0.0.1826-b10_0_0_1826.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libodbc.so.1()(64bit)
           Removing: unixODBC-2.2.11-7.1.x86_64 (installed)
               libodbc.so.1()(64bit)
           Updated By: unixODBC-2.2.14-14.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-server-fastrack-rpms)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Are you using NCentral monitoring? That installs nagent-rhel_64 package with its own provided dependencies, outside `yum`, and caused this error for me.

Comment: Yes I am. How did you resolve it?

Comment: It wasn't clean; I think it needs `libodbc.so.1` which was provided by `unixODBC`, but the latest unixODBC release has `.so.2` instead (guessing a lot here). I know my server does nothing database related, so I did `yum remove unixODBC` and the packages from the nagent installer, then `yum update`, then reinstalled nagent. I had to leave unixODBC out completely. If I needed database connectivity, I'd have raised it with their support, as it seems like an incompatibility with a new update. `libodbc.so.1` is included in their files - there might be a way to say to use it, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem recently, and yes I use N-Central on both Red Hat and CentOS.

I used the yum.conf file to "exclude" the unixODBC from the update process.

I simply added the following to the end of the configuration lines in /etc/yum.conf

exclude=unixODBC*

Then proceeded to run yum update.

I found this at this [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redhat-centos-linux-yum-update-exclude-packages/).

Answer (score 1):

Your local copy of the repository metadata is out of sync with what the repositories contain.

Clear your metadata and try again.

```
yum clean metadata
```

or

```
yum clean all
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I've tried that and then re-run `yum update` and still getting the same message

Comment: Are you getting updates from Satellite? It could be a problem there.

Comment: Not that I know of, I only have a basic self service subscription to RHEL